# How to get a base class?

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I created this type:

```
 public class ImageHolder :Image<Bgr,byte>
    {   
        private String imagePath;

        public ImageHolder(String path):base()
        {
           this.imagePath = path;            
        }

        public String imgPathProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return imagePath;
            }
            set
            {
                imagePath = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the instance of the class:

```
ImageHolder sd = new ImageHolder("path");
```

I need to get the base type of SignDetection type.

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> img = sd.BaseType;
```

Any idea how can I implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming that `SignDetection` is also derived from `Image<Bgr, byte>` (your question is misleading): `Image<Bgr, byte> img = sd;`

Comment: I guess `SignDetection` and `ImageHolder` are the same thing, right? You want one and not the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to cast to "the base type". Your `ImageHolder` instance is *also* an `Image<Bgr,Byte>` instance, so:

`Image<Bgr,Byte> img = sd;`

Comment: That's a whole different issue that has nothing to do with casting. If you had a problem with the object types, your could wouldn't pass compilation.

Answer (score 1):

use reflection `this.GetType().BaseType`